# How to get header cell name when dragging and dropping cell content

Tags: javascript

am here trying to perform drag and drop operations on cell data here what i want to do is,get the cell header name of the cell where am dropping content ,here am able to get cell header of that cell where am dragging content
this is the code am using for drag and drop functionality

```
<table id="#our_table"  border="1">
<tr>
<th>head1</th>
<th>head1</th>
<th>head1</th>
</tr>
<tr><th>Row1<th>
<td><span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">aaa</span></td>
<td><span class="event" id="b" draggable="true">bbb</span></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Row2<th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
              var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
              dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
            });
        $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {  
           event.preventDefault();
           if (event.type === 'drop') {
              var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
              if($(this).find('span').length===0){
                   de=$('#'+data).detach();
                   de.appendTo($(this));    
                  }

           };
       });
})
```

[fiddle for drag and drop functinality](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/2RuBh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use index of current cell to fetch the header.

Here is my answer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
                var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
            });
            $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.type === 'drop') {
                    var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
                    if ($(this).find('span').length === 0) {
                        de = $('#' + data).detach();
                        index = $(this).index();
                        headerText = $("table th").eq(index).text();
                        console.log(headerText);
                        alert(headerText);
                        de.appendTo($(this));
                    }

                }
                ;
            });
        })
```

And here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/toLvzrLp/3/

Comment: if i wan to do the same with the first cell of every row then how can i do that?means i want to display cell header and first cell of that row where am dropping my content

Comment: You can use closest() function to select row in which you drag your cell then use find() to get first td like this  firstColText = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/toLvzrLp/4/

Comment: i have one more doubt,can we do the same at dragstart event?

Comment: Yes you can use closest() to find parent tr (row) or td (cell) of span element on dragstart event

Comment: do you want first col text and header there same like drop event?

Comment: var header=$(this).closest('tr').find('td').text();    
like this?

Comment: No, to get header text you need to right like this
index = $(this).closest('td').index();
headerText = $("table th").eq(index).text();

Comment: i got that by 
var firstCell= $(this).closest('td').parent('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();

Comment: and thanks it was helpful to me to resolve a biggest issue of mine

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it would be helpful to you or not but you can add that header's name as property for your td and then at time of drag&drop you can access that.

For Example.

```
<table id="#our_table"  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>head1</th>
    <th>head1</th>
    <th>head1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="event head1" id="a" draggable="true">aaa</span></td>
    <td><span class="event head2" id="b" draggable="true">bbb</span></td>
    <td><span class="head3"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="head1"></span></td>
    <td><span class="head2"></span></td>
    <td><span class="head3"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
             var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
             dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
             var headName=$(this).attr('class').remove('event');
        });
    $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {  
       event.preventDefault();
       if (event.type === 'drop') {
          var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
          if($(this).find('span').length===0){
               de=$('#'+data).detach();
               de.appendTo($(this));    
              }

       };
   });
});
```